# SQL Average By Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL and having struggle trying to find out the average from beginning of the year (January) to the current month. For example, it should show the average from January to August as a column. I don't know how to get the AVG from column names until a specific month (current month):

```
select
    [Customer], category,
    [1] AS January, [2] AS Febrary, [3] AS March,
    [4] AS April, [5] AS May, [6] AS June,
    [7] AS July, [8] AS August, [9] AS September,
    [10] AS October, [11] AS November, [12] AS December 
from
    (select
         month(received) as my_month, [Customer], category 
     from
         Data 
     where 
         year(Received) = '2017') AS t
pivot 
    (count(my_month) for my_month IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) as p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, category,
       sum(case when month(received) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(received) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
       . . .,
       sum(case when month(received) <= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as thru_jan,
       sum(case when month(received) <= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as thru_feb,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(received) >= 1 and month(received) <= month(getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) as uptonow
from data
where received >= '2017-01-01' and received < '2018-01-01'
group by customer, category;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your response. Sorry, so by using the conditional aggregation I can get a column that adds the sum for Month from January until the current month? Im having a bit hard time understanding this.

Comment: @user3314399 . . . I added the logic in the column `uptonow`.

Comment: thank you Gordon! Everything returned correct value expect uptonow shows 0 for all the rows.

Comment: Thank you SO SO MUCH! It worked great after the edit!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you're approaching this from a completely wrong standpoint. Something like this should return an average of the current year until the beginning of the current month grouped by customer and category:

```
SELECT AVG(received), Customer, Category
  FROM Data
  WHERE YEAR(Received) = 2017 
    AND MONTH(Received) < MONTH(GETDATE())
  GROUP BY Customer, Category
```

Comment: Thank you Lassi. But, Im looking to add a new column at the end of the quary Called Average_TODate Where it takes the average from columns January to the end of current month (August) in this case. Sorry if I was not being clear on my explanation.